# What is a word for the opposite party in a trade?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example the person that starts the trade is the *initiator* of the trade, so what is the other person known as? Is there a word like *initiator* for the opposite party?

Comment: Trade in what?  In the stock market (or the pot market) it would usually be a *dealer*.

Comment: @HotLicks Are you sure about dealer? It doesn't seem like the right word. Doesn't *dealer* mean someone who sells or maybe even buys things? Whereas this is like a swap. I mean like a olden style trade consisting of physical goods. So a hat for a boot or a boot for a cap.

Comment: I think this is the language of web-service e-businesses.

Comment: Under the law of contract (in the UK), in order for a contract to exist, there has to be evidence of an *offer* and an *acceptance* (neither of which necessarily has to be in writing). The parties are called various things but these elements to a trade, whether it be for goods or services, must exist for any contract to be enforceable in law.

Comment: @WS2 thank you for the reply, but I'm unsure how all relates to me? I'm just trying to get a word to describe the opposite party.

Comment: @Script47 - Dealing in stocks in the stock market is known as "trading".

Comment: @HotLicks ah probably should have clarified, I mean like the olden day type trading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [***counterparty***](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/counterparty.asp#ixzz3pukfJWpe) -
>
> The other party that participates in a financial transaction. Every transaction must have a counterparty in order for the transaction to go through. More specifically, every buyer of an asset must be paired up with a seller that is willing to sell and vice versa.

Literally means the "opposite party."

Comment: I +1'd this and will accept this answer as I feel it is the correct word, however I will wait for other answers before I accept just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Recipient. In sports, the compound noun "receiving end" is common. Webster's Dictionary does not hyphenate.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it must be **responder.**

This shows up in some search results, e.g.

[VPN Gateway Device Configured as Responder in Crypto Negotiation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/pix-500-series-security-appliances/113158-crypto-responder-only.html)

Comment: Surely?  This is a piece of hardware, not a person.

Comment: I am serious and don't call me Shirley! http://i.lvme.me/f48yt35.jpg

Comment: Well, Shirley, you're right.  Your cite is just inapt.